# How can one view the day-by-day net worth for a period of more than 30 days on Mint?

Tags: mint.com, net-worth, tracking

Mint has a feature to view one's net worth: https://help.mint.com/Trends/961902851/How-can-I-see-my-net-worth.htm By default if the selected duration (last 7 days, last 14 days, etc.) is more than 30 days, then the graph shows a month-by-month net worth.

How can one view the day-by-day net worth for a period of more than 30 days on Mint?

---

Example of month-by-month net worth in Mint ([image source](http://www.mylifeinsidemyhead.com/mint/)):

[image]

Example of day-by-day net worth in Personal Capital ([image source](https://www.biggerpockets.com/blog/personal-capital-review)):

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell that is not supported, but this is probably a better question for Intuit support than this site.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Mint's customer service:

> Unfortunately, Mint does not have this feature available at this time.

Alternatives:

- Display a 30-day period, export it, repeat for all 30-day periods. Could be automated e.g. via Sikuli.
- Export transactions and reconstruct the daily net worth.